# Loop through a DataGridView and add values where rows are checked

Tags: c#

I have a C# application and I have DataGridView which I can either bind to a datasource or dynamically load data but is irrelevant to what I need to do.

To Illustarte - I have three columns. The first column is a checkbox followed by an ID column which is not unique and can contain duplciates and then an Amount column.

I need to load the data into seperate rows so I do not want to accumulate the dataset before populating the DataGridView as the user will select the values to mark off so - I want to loop through the the datagridview and for all checked rows, accumulate or sum up the amount column where the ID's are the same.

As an example, below is a sample of the data.
ID    Amount
1     50.25
2     15.20
3     66.95
1     12.01
3     15.15
1     85.27

If we assume that the first two records for ID 1 are checked, I want to loop through the DataGridView and add the amounts together and have one amount for all checked rows
but in this case for ID 1 (50.25 + 12.01 = 62.26)

Any Suggestions?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What are you having trouble with here? Looping over either the grid's row collection or over a backing datasource should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have LINQ, then something along these lines might work (without any code that is). Obviously it will need modified for your own code, but the idea is there. You can get each grouping's sum from this.

```
ListOfDataRows.Where(x => x.Checked)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.ColumnWithId)
    .Sum(x => x.ColumnWithValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to do all the computations:

```
var summedRows = yourDataGridView
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => (bool)r.Cells[0].Value == true) 
    .GroupBy(r => r.Cells[1].Value)
    .Select(g => new 
        { 
            Id = g.Key, 
            Sum = g.Sum(r => (double)r.Cells[2].Value) 
        }
    );
```

All you need to do now is build new `DataGridViewRows` collection basing on those values.

**Edit:**

In case your grid contains *"add new row"* dummy row (the last one), you want to skip it in your query:

```
var summedRows = yourDataGridView
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
    .Take(yourDataGridView.Rows.Count - 1)
    // rest same as above
```